# Matlab : Is it possible to check whole licenses with matlab 'license' command?

Tags: matlab, licensing

I would like to check my matlab license.

I refered this link, [enter link description here](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/ref/license.html)

With `license('inuse')` command, I knew I can check out current using license.

With `license('checkout',feature)`, I knew I can check out whether certain license exists or not.

But, my concern is to check whole available matlab licenses of my PC(I have server license).

Are there any functions to check all available licenses something like `license('all')`?

Comment: You could check the licenses file in the installation path, in my case is network.lic, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: My concern is to find whole available tools for me, something like 'communication toolbox', 'simmechanics'. When I checked network.lic file,  I couldn't find the licensed tool names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a brute force kind of checkout with something like

```
names={'MATLAB','SIMULINK','Aerospace_Blockset','Aerospace_Toolbox','Bioinformatics_Toolbox','Communication_Blocks','Communication_Toolbox','Control_Toolbox','Curve_Fitting_Toolbox','Data_Acq_Toolbox','Database_Toolbox','Datafeed_Toolbox','EDA_Simulator_Link_DS','Link_for_Incisive','Link_for_ModelSim','Econometrics_Toolbox','MATLAB_Link_for_CCS','IDE_Link_MU','Link_for_Tasking','Link_for_VisualDSP','Excel_Link','Filter_Design_HDL_Coder','Filter_Design_Toolbox','Fin_Derivatives_Toolbox','Financial_Toolbox','Fixed_Income_Toolbox','Fixed_Point_Toolbox','Fuzzy_Toolbox','Dial_and_Gauge_Blocks','GADS_Toolbox','Image_Acquisition_Toolbox','Image_Toolbox','Instr_Control_Toolbox','MATLAB_Excel_Builder','MATLAB_Builder_for_Java','MATLAB_Builder_for_dot_Net','Compiler','MATLAB_Report_Gen','MAP_Toolbox','MPC_Toolbox','MBC_Toolbox','Neural_Network_Toolbox','OPC_Toolbox','Optimization_Toolbox','Distrib_Computing_Toolbox','PDE_Toolbox','RF_Blockset','RF_Toolbox','Real-Time_Win_Target','RTW_Embedded_Coder','Real-Time_Workshop','Robust_Toolbox','Signal_Blocks','Signal_Toolbox','SimBiology','SimDriveline','SimElectronics','SimEvents','SimHydraulics','SimMechanics','Power_System_Blocks','Simscape','Simulink_Control_Design','Simulink_Design_Verifier','Fixed-Point_Blocks','Simulink_HDL_Coder','Simulink_Param_Estimation','SIMULINK_Report_Gen','NCD_Toolbox','SL_Verification_Validation','Spline_Toolbox','Stateflow_Coder','Stateflow','Statistics_Toolbox','Symbolic_Toolbox','Identification_Toolbox','SystemTest','Embedded_Target_MPC555','Embedded_Target_c166','Embedded_Target_c2000','Embedded_Target_c6000','Video_and_Image_Blockset','Virtual_Reality_Toolbox','Wavelet_Toolbox','XPC_Embedded_Option','XPC_Target'};

out=[];
for x=names

    if license('test',char(x))
        out=[out;x];
    end
end

out
```

I got the list from here http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91651-what-is-a-list-of-all-licenses-that-can-be-queried-by-the-license-command-in-matlab-7-7-r2008b , I don't know if it is a complete list

Also I think that if you have the login information of the mathworks account you can check it there

Comment: It works well, thank you~, But I am little worried about matlab version. My version is 2015a. Changing names or adding new tools would be possible.

Comment: @김갑수 Point would be to find the updated list of all possible toolboxes, I guess that it is somewhere in the mathworks page.

Comment: Ok~ I will search it.